# Why does a p-type conduction band have higher energy then n-type conduction band in a p-n junction?

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction, electron

In an energy band diagram that represents the p-n junction (during equilibrium) the p-type conduction band has greater energy then an n-type conduction band. Why does the p-type have greater energy when the n-type has much more free electrons?

Comment: By "p-type conduction band" do you mean the conduction band within the p-type semiconductor?

Comment: Yes, I mean the conduction band in the p-type semi-conductor.

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right lines with thinking about the electrons, but need to consider one more thing:

The energy band diagram of a *p-n*-junction at equilibrium is dependent on the *Fermi Level* for each material. The Fermi level is the theoretical energy level at which the probability of finding an electron is 50%. As a *p*-type material has an excess number of holes, *i.e.* fewer electrons, the Fermi level lies closer to the valence band. Then for an *n*-type material that has electrons occupying the conduction band, the energy at which the likelihood of finding an electron is 50% is therefore increased.

As at equilibrium, the Fermi levels must match in a *p-n*-junction, this leads to the *p*-type conduction band existing at a greater energy relative to the *n*-type conduction band.

Comment: What causes the Fermi level to be the same for both p and n type?

Comment: The Fermi Level match is a requirement of equilibrium (similar to chemical potentials of two systems aligning when brought together) - otherwise current would flow.

Comment: I have one last question. When this same semi-conductor is attached reverse biased the n-type receives a net positive charge (because it loses electrons) where as the p-type  becomes negatively charged. When you look at the band diagram for reverse bias you see that the conduction band increases which means that electrons need more energy to go into the conduction band. Why do electrons need more energy (for the p-type) when there are now more electrons?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - in reverse bias the applied field serves to increase that of the depletion region, this makes it harder for the electrons to cross.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your cause and effect backward. The high energy level of the conduction band in the p-type semiconductor is why the p-type semiconductor has mostly holes and few electrons.

First I need to make a correction to your question. The p-type semiconductor doesn't have greater energy than the n-type semiconductor. This is because the semiconductor itself doesn't really have an energy. Charge carriers (electrons/holes) have energies. The relative positioning of the bands tell you how much energy an electron or a hole must have for it to exist. In the n-type semiconductor, you have a lot of free electrons because it requires very little energy to fill those electron states. However, in a p-type semiconductor, it requires a lot of energy to fill the electron states in the conduction band. It is precisely this reason that there are not a lot of electrons in the p-type semiconductor. This is what makes it a p-type semiconductor.

Comment: I have one last question. When this same semi-conductor is attached reverse biased the n-type receives a net positive charge (because it loses electrons) where as the p-type becomes negatively charged. When you look at the band diagram for reverse bias you see that the conduction band increases(for the p-type) which means that electrons need more energy to go into the conduction band. Why do electrons need more energy (for the p-type) when there are now more electrons present?

Comment: @FaheemAzeemi Applying a reverse bias is setting up an electric field that would cause electrons to move from the p side to the n side (and the holes the other way) An electron or hole that goes the wrong way would need to be a exceptionally energetic. This part is the same as in a uniform block of semiconductor.

Answer (score 1):

**Not sure how accurate my answer. Would really appreciate some feedback.**

To create holes, electrons are excited from the valence band to the conduction band. Energy is supplied as the electron is released. The energy supplied increases the energy of both the ambient energy of the nucleus as well as the electron.
*This increases the overall energy of the system.*

Furthermore, to remove the electron from the conduction band, energy is supplied.
*Further increasing the energy of the system.*

This leads to p-type semiconductor having higher energy level than n-type.

Answer (score -1):

Here we have two type of electrons.one is p typed and other is n typed.
We have few points to note:
1.More no.of holes in p type.
2.few electrons in p type that to they are in conduction band.
Here you can interpret that the electrons in p type must escape from it's broken atom and remaining all holes this happens when the electron is at almost near to 0 level where it is free from everything .where as in n type the electron is surrounded by mostly other electrons here it has no any attracting force so it is need not to be very far that is more energy near to 0 level.Hence the ectrons in p type(p type conduction band) has more energy than n type (n type conduction band).

Comment: This text is a too confused, too many filling words, imprecise vocabulary, for most people incl. me to make any sense of it and even judge its correctness.