# In an energy band diagram why is the valance band in the p-type have more energy then n-type?

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction, electron

I am having trouble understanding energy band diagrams. In an energy band diagram of a semi-conductor during equilibrium the valence band of the p-type is higher then n-type meaning electrons in the valence band of p-type semi-conductors have greater energy but how is this possible when p-type semi-conductor have holes which attract electrons and should therefore, not need much energy?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a p-type conduction band have higher energy then n-type conduction band in a p-n junction?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524619/why-does-a-p-type-conduction-band-have-higher-energy-then-n-type-conduction-band)

Comment: It talks about the conduction band rather then the valence band.