# What does the fermi-level increase in reverse-bias?

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction, electron

Fermi-level tells us the probability of finding an electron at 50%. When you look at an energy band diagram in reverse-bias you can see the Fermi-level increases in the p-type semi-conductor. Why does this occur?

My second question is why does the energy of the valence band increase? Shouldn't it be less because it has a lot of holes?

Comment: You should probably first read [hyperphysics: Fermi Level](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/Fermi.html) before you make assumptions or trust the words of others here about the meaning of the Fermi level. There is another concept, the Fermi surface (which can be a rather complex shape in solid state physics.) Get the axioms squared up, first. One the bricks are placed well, you can build up from there. (Your idea of about the energy of a valence band increasing needs some more thought, for example.) I think you are headed towards more confusion, if left with these ideas.

Comment: How is your second part question different from your previous question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524619/

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for for the first part other than "Applying a voltage necessarily changes the relative energies of the two regions. Thats what voltage is."?

Comment: @jonk I have a very limited background in semiconductor-physics. What should be the first thing I should read.

Comment: @FaheemAzeemi Well, your questions are deeper than most "microelectronics" courses. If you really want to get a feel for this stuff, you'll want to delve into solid state physics. Feynman's Lecture series recommends: C. Kittel, "Introduction to Solid State Physics," John Wiley and Sons, Inc., New York, 2nd ed., 1956. I'd think that's as good as any. And it's from the right period, as well, that it should have fewer prior expectations from the reader. I'd give that one a shot, to start. You can always go read Feynman's Lecture series, too. It covers a great deal of background material.

Comment: @jonk Can you send me the link.

Comment: @FaheemAzeemi It worries me a great deal that you plan to go study this stuff and cannot be bothered to lift a finger to use google. That doesn't bode well for the idea that you'll do the work needed to read the materials with understanding and effort. Is it blocked in your area of the world?

Comment: @jonk No it's not blocked. I did search google before I asked you for the link and the website you recommended does not seem to come up. (I wrote Feynman's Lecture series recommends: C. Kittel, "Introduction to Solid State Physics," John Wiley and Sons, Inc., New York, 2nd ed., 1956. ) I should have stated that before I stated my obvious question.

Comment: @FaheemAzeemi Just search for Feynman Lecture Series. That will take you to a good place. Go to chapter 30 of the second volume and start there. Read everything from there to the end of volume 3. Go back to earlier sections, as needed. The book by Kittel is entirely different. Do not include Feynman in that search.